# Поочередное изменение знаков(i *= -1) всех чисел в массиве;

Tags: c#

Напишите функцию, которая будет менять в массиве целых чисел все элементы, которые равны указанному значению (аргумент) на противоположное значение по знаку. Например, все элементы массива которые равны 5, будут меняться на -5.

Много вариантов перепробовал,Буду очень признателен если кто то укажет на ошибку.

```
public static int GetMinus(int[] number)
{
    int ivan = 0;
    foreach (int el in number)
       {
       ivan = el * -1;
       } 
        return ivan;
    }


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] number = { 1, 2, 3, 4, -5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, -22, 33, 44, 55, -66, -77, 88, 99 };
    int minus;
    minus = GetMinus(number);
    Console.WriteLine(minus);
    Console.ReadKey();


}
```

Выдает в большей части попыток -1 либо 1, в данном -99.

Comment: У тебя в задании написано, что должен быть аргумент, если значение массива равно ему, то значение меняется. У тебя в коде я вижу, что ты абсолютно у каждого элемента меняешь условие. Тебе как минимум надо добавить аргумент и условие в твой метод

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну как-то так можно, к примеру:

```
public static void GetAdditiveInverseForNumber(int[] inputArray, int number)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < inputArray.Length; index++)
    {
        if (inputArray[index] == number)
        {
            inputArray[index] *= -1;
        }
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var changeNumber = 5; // какое число будем менять
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, -22, 33, 44, 5, -66, -77, 88, 99 };

    Console.WriteLine("До преобразования: ");
    foreach (var num in numbers)
        Console.WriteLine(num);

    GetAdditiveInverseForNumber(numbers, changeNumber);

    Console.WriteLine("После преобразования: ");
    foreach (var num in numbers)
        Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

Все цифры, которые совпадут - будут изменены. То, что Вы пытаетесь сделать...ну мягко говоря - это не то, что нужно.

Comment: `ref` здесь совершенно не к месту. `Array` в .NET - ссылочный тип.

Comment: @Igor, пардон. Точно. Затупил на ночь глядя

Comment: Попробуйте без `ref`. Минус я уберу - не проблема.

Comment: @Igor, спасибо. Я по привычке как к списку объектов машинально написал `ref`.